# Visual Studio 2012 Unit Tests not running remotly because of NuGet error

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I am running VS 2012 (Version 11.0.61030.00 Update 4).  I created a project to run unit tests which had been working 100%.  I have 2 test settings profiles.  One for running tests local (still works fine) and another for running test remotely (using a test controller and test agents).  All tests worked back in Feb. 2014.  I have not run them until today.  I receive the following error in the Visual Studio output window for tests:

```
Cannot discover test extensions installed by NuGet. The NuGet service is not 
available. Tests may not be found due to missing test adapter extensions. The 
connection to the controller was lost.
```

As far as I know I never configured NuGet in the first place.  At this point, I don't really want to use it until I thoroughly research the technology.  It is quite possible I updated the Visual Studio software between Feb and now, but I don't think so.  Why do I have a sudden dependecy on NuGet?
What can I do to fix this?  I suppose this could be a bogus message and my real problem is something else entirely, but hopefully someone else has seen this.

NOTE: connection is not an issue.  I have a solid drive mapping from VS2012 machine to Test Controller.  Tests do not deploy to controller or to test agent machines.  Problem is not limited to Unit Test project.  I have a CUITest project with the same issue, but let's stick to unit test project for this post.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message I was seeing referring to NuGet had nothing to do with my issue.  Yes, I would see this message during test execution, but I'm also seeing it during builds.  The message was likely always there I just failed to notice it.  My problem was actually tied to something else and since I could ignore the Nuget message, I focused more on the "connection to the controller was lost" message.

So now my issue:  As stated I had a solid connection from VS2012 to the controller.  However, you also need a connection from the controller back to the VS2012 machine.  There was a connectivity issue in that direction due to my DHCP address changing (lease expired).  So there was no code issue.  It was an environment issue.  The NuGet error was just a distracting waste of time.